# Gateway method-name as header value

Tags: spring-integration

I have a Gateway with a default-request-channel an multiple methods.

```
public interface IUserService {
 public void updateUserName(Long id, String username);
 public void updatePassword(Long id, String password);
 ...
}
```

and the following xml config

```
...
<gateway id="userService" service-interface="...IUserService"
         default-request-channel="dataRequestChannel" 
         default-reply-channel="dataResponseChannel" />
...
```

How can i get information about the method which is invoked ?

I know that it is possible to apply static header values but is that the only way ?
Or am i totally wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an [open JIRA issue for this](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-3069) feature; please vote it up.

Right now, the #method variable is available in expressions within specific method declarations

```
<int:gateway id="gw"
    service-interface="foo.Gateway"
    default-request-channel="input">
    <int:method name="sendAndReceive">
        <int:header name="gwMethod" expression="#method"/>
    </int:method>
</int:gateway>
```

But you would still have to declare each method.

Perhaps another, relatively simple enhancement would be to support wildcards in method names; something like...

```
<int:gateway id="gw"
    service-interface="foo.Gateway"
    default-request-channel="input">
    <int:method name="*">
        <int:header name="gwMethod" expression="#method"/>
    </int:method>
</int:gateway>
```

Where headers for method `*` would be added for all methods.

Comment: Ok, i will vote for it. I think the wildcard solution would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.0.1 you can do the following to set headers across all methods accessed via the gateway (you can also manage the specific methods as usual).

I am showing how to set two header properties, transportType and methodType, one dynamic and one static:

```
<int:gateway id="gw" 
    service-interface="foo.async.Gateway" 
    default-request-channel="gateway-request-channel"
    default-reply-channel="gateway-response-channel">
    <int:default-header name="transportType" value="async-msg"/>
    <int:default-header name="methodType" expression="#gatewayMethod.name"/>
</int:gateway>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-configuration-annotations

A bit late but the correct solution for those following this thread later.